# How to calculate focal length of fisheye camera

Tags: fisheye

i am currently try to undistort a fisheye image. To undistort a fisheye image intrinsic matrix is needed. but currently i am provided with image size and maximum FOV, it is possible to calculate focal length of fisheye image with image size and maximum FOV?

know the method to calculate fisheye image focal length in order to compute its intrinsic matrix

Comment: Your problem is more one of raytracing geometry than programming. Fish eye lenses tend to be 10mm or shorter for a standard 35mm camera frame (and scale lineaRLY with the dimensions of the image sensor). The distortions stem from the fact that tan(x) ~ x only for small values of x. Some image processing packages offer it as a feature for particular makers lenses.